# Please identify this flowering plant

Tags: identification

Found this growing in my garden in the back.

Growing Location/Conditions:
semi-shady area, Pennsylvania, USA with regular amount of yearly rain

Photos:
[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: In Europe, I would go to daisy and relatives: Leucanthemum or Tanacetum

Comment: I had a thought but it wasn't correct - sorry.